# UAC spontaneously turned on?

Tags: windows-7, uac

I told [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to monitor the system boot, and then rebooted.

The system started, but some some programs started freezing.

From exploring the symptoms a bit I suspected it was the antivirus, so I turned off Microsoft Security Essentials and told ProcMon to monitor the boot again, and then rebooted.

This time it booted fine, but then UAC suddenly got enabled!

Why would this happen?

#### Edit:

It seems like a bunch of the Group Policies are also reset, not just UAC. :\

Comment: Could be a virus.  How did you disable UAC?

Comment: @HarryJohnston: A *virus*? When I told Process Monitor to *log the boot* process? That makes no sense to me. It's been fine for more than a year with UAC turned off (through User Accounts)

Comment: So by "turned off" you mean "configured to never notify"?  An existing virus might have changed behaviour when you disabled your antivirus software.  But it could just as easily be a random glitch.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Yes. I *really* don't think it's a virus... I've had no (other) signs of viruses on this computer whatsoever... but then I don't understand how a "glitch" like this could happen, even though it's the most likely explanation right now.

Comment: It's sounding as if the interaction between ProcMon and MSE has corrupted your registry.